# AWS EMR Bootstrap addition or update

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I've created a AWS EMR cluster. Is it possible to add bootstrap action to this existing EMR cluster? I'm planning to use it only for task nodes(during auto-scaling).

I've gone through the [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) and I'm able to find it(bootstrap addition) mentioned only during create-cluster action.

So, I'd like to know is it possible to add/update bootstrap action to existing cluster?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can only if you use a bootstrap action from S3. By changing the script and on auto-scaling the new script will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** add bootstrap script or change script location **after** cluster creation, but you can edit the script if a cluster already has bootstrap enabled.